# Euclidean Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity, singularities

I am studying the Euclidean Schwarzschild metric and trying to find its isometries. It still has $\partial_{\phi}$ as a Killing vector, but I wonder if the range of $\phi$ is still $0$ to $2\pi$. The following metric,

$ds^2=dr^2+(r+2M)^2d\phi^2$

where $0<r<\infty$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$, is a constant time slice of a 3D Euclidean Schwarzschild metric. I have redefined $r$ which still runs from $0$ to $\infty$ because it is Euclidean. Does this metric have a non curvature singularity at $r=0$? If so, is it possible to remove it by changing the range of $\phi$?